# Vba Macro in Word for exporting files from Excel in Word with prompt

Tags: excel, ms-word, prompt, vba

I'm starting with VBA, I create a macro in Excel for exporting data in Word:

```
Sub ExportToWord()
    Set obj = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    obj.Visible = True
    Set newobj = obj.Documents.Add

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        ws.UsedRange.Copy
        newobj.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
        newobj.ActiveWindow.Selection.InsertBreak Type:=7
    Next
        newobj.ActiveWindow.Selection.TypeBackspace
        newobj.ActiveWindow.Selection.TypeBackspace

    obj.Activate
    newobj.SaveAs Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\OLD\" & Split(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".")(0)
End Sub
```

I would like to do the same but directly from Word (without opening Excel) with a prompt for selecting the origin folder (with Excel files) and the destination folder (Word files created with the script).

Could you please help me to do that?

Regards

Comment: so, you want to import an Excel workbook into Word?

Comment: I think this is a *hen egg problem*. You need to run your VBA code either (1) in Word (this has to be open) and **import** something from Excel (therefore the Excel file has to be opened by the VBA code, this can be done hidden). OR (2) in Excel (this has to be open) and **export** data to Word. (3) There is no other option with VBA. One has to be open to run the VBA code either Word OR Excel. (4) Please also read [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) and improve your question.

Comment: Great, I'm looking just to do that all in Word, but I don't know if my VB Excel script above can work directly in Word and how to implement the prompt

Comment: You still need to "open" workbook in Excel, you can't read data from closed one.

Comment: No, it won't work in Word without improving it. You will need to open the Excel file (which can be done hidden and read only, there are a bunch of tutorials for that if you google). And you need to try to achieve that on your own first and show us what you tried, where you got stuck or where you got any errors (and which). Because this is not a we-do-your-work-for-free website. Come up with the code you tried to do it in Word and we possibly can help you to improve it if you tell us where your **specific** issues are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create the script for responding to the need:

```
Private Sub ExportExcelToWord_Click()

  Dim xlApp As Object 'Excel.Application
  Dim xlWb As Object 'Excel.Workbook
  Dim xlWs As Object 'Excel.Worksheet
  Dim wdApp As Object 'Word.Application
  Dim wdDoc As Object 'Word.Document
  Dim Path As String
  Dim i As Long

  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  xlApp.EnableEvents = False
  xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Choose the destination folder for Word documents"
    If Not .Show Then Exit Sub
    Path = .SelectedItems(1)
    If Right(Path, 1) <> "\" Then Path = Path & "\"
  End With

  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Title = "Choose the folder with Excel original documents"
    .Filters.Add "Excel files", "*.xls*"
    If Not .Show Then Exit Sub

    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wdApp.Visible = True
    wdApp.DisplayAlerts = 0 'wdAlertsNone

    For i = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
      Set xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(i), False, True)
      Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add

      For Each xlWs In xlWb.Worksheets
        wdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.TypeText xlWs.Name
        wdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Style = wdDoc.Styles(-2)
        wdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.TypeParagraph

        xlWs.UsedRange.Copy
        wdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
        wdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.InsertBreak Type:=7
      Next
      wdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.TypeBackspace
      wdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.TypeBackspace
      wdDoc.SaveAs Path & Split(xlWb.Name, ".")(0)
      wdDoc.Close False
      xlWb.Close False
    Next
  End With
  On Error Resume Next
  wdApp.Quit
  xlApp.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: So, do you have issues with this? Or is this your working solution? If it is a solution then you can accept your own answer as solution.